# Web api: Как получить значение из формы и установить его для asp-action

Tags: asp.net-web-api, razor

Собственно говоря есть метод который прекрасно работает если писать запрос вручную или с приложения:

```
// GET: api/contractor/showContractor/1
[HttpGet("ShowContractor/{id:int}")] 
public IActionResult ShowContractor(int id)
   {
      var contractor = GetContractor(id).Result.Value;
      return View(contractor);
   }
```

Кнопка указанная ниже тоже прекрасно работает:

```
<a asp-controller="Contractor" asp-action="ShowContractor" asp-route-id="1" class="button">Показать</a>
```

Но я никак не могу заставить работать ее вместе с полем, т.е. в поле вводиться значение и это значение поставляется под id.

```
<div class="container">
    <form method="get" asp-controller="Contractor" asp-action="ShowContractor">
        <label>Исполнитель №</label>
        <input type="number" name="id"/>
        <input class="button" type="submit" value="Показать"/>
    </form>
</div>
```

Помогите пожалуйста уже и в хвост и в гриву, а представление с методом никак не выходит.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Для передачи чего-либо из форм на странице, которые может выбирать Пользователь. В представлении в первой строке кода, всегда указывается модель с которой будет работать это представление. Для вашего случая, видимо это будет модель Contractor. Так что, сначала необходимо в каком-то из представлений, создать форму, в которой заполняется Id для какого-то экземпляра объекта Contractor. Далее, необходимо создать метод типа POST, в который передается модель с нужным Id, и в нем, вызывается метод типа GET с таким экземпляром объекта.
   Для вашей задачи, чтобы не путаться можно изменить сигнатуры методов

   ```
    public IActionResult ShowContractorGet(Contractor _contractor)
    {
        // код для извлечения объекта из БД
        var contractor = new Contractor();
        contractor.Id = _contractor.Id;
        contractor.Name = "Test";
        return View(contractor);

    }
   ```

далее Атрибут `[HttpPost]`
и сам метод пост, который будет вызываться из представления

```
public IActionResult ShowContractorPost(Contractor _contractor)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("ShowContractorGet", _contractor);
        }
```

2. В представлении нужно явно указать, что это форма для ввода данных, добавляяя строку `form method="post"`

   ```
    <div class="container">
    <form method="post" asp-controller="Contractor" asp-action="ShowContractorPost">
        <div>
            <label asp-for ="Id"></label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input asp-for="Id" class="form-control"/>
        </div>


        <input class="button" type="submit" value="Показать" />
    </form>
   ```
3. Однако, такой подход, когда вы даете пользователю право выбирать произвольный Id, в том числе и несуществующего объекта, не самая лучшая практика.  Правильнее сначала создать метод и представление к нему, в котором выводится список, всех существующих объектов. Далее по названию объекта пользователь может выбрать произвольный, существующий объект, при этом значение Id, будет скрыто от него, но доступно для передачи его значения, в случае выбора такого объекта и дальнейшей работы с ним. Именно такой подход для реализации  [CRUD](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/CRUD)-операций, реализован в этом [репозитории](https://github.com/AndyBrizhak/Rocky), с рабочим кодом для приложения с ASP.NET Core MVC на .NET 5.
4. Если вы хотите использовать для решения ваших задач WEB-API, то можете посмотреть аналогичный подход в этом [репозитории](https://github.com/AndyBrizhak/Mango), с рабочим кодом, где основное front-end приложение построено на ASP.NET Core MVC, а микросервисы к нему сделаны с WEB-API для .NET 6.

Comment: К сожалению первый пункт не работает, если изменить на метод пост то он не вызывается, если убрать параметр {id:int} то метод вызываеть но связка ID из представления с ID из метода не происходит, т.е. Значение всегда 0

Comment: Исправил ответ,  вот в этом репозитории рабочий [код](https://github.com/AndyBrizhak/ProjectFromStackOverflow) вашего примера.

Comment: В перегрузках для метода RedirectToAction, базового класса Controller,  я не нашел такого варианта, где после ссылки на другой метод, передается параметр типа Int, поэтому в репозитории нагородил костыли, но они работают.